# What is a quick way to determine how many typed holes to give to a function?

Tags: haskell, typed-holes

[Typed holes](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Typed_holes) offer a great way of finding out how to implement something: if you know what function to use, say `foo`, you can just write out something like `foo _ _ _` and let the compiler tell you what types it expects for each argument. This makes it largely unnecessary to look up any documentation.

However, it only works properly if you actually write out the correct *number* of underscores. At the moment, I usually determine this by some trial-and-error, but it's not always obvious what hints to look out for, because in Haskell functions can always be just partially applied.

What is a good way to find out this number as quickly as possible?

Comment: @hnefatl I think, person with golden badge in Haskell category knows about `:type` command... :) But question is about fast ways of finding correct number of arguments for some function. As it seems for me, open `ghci`, load module with `foo` function, then print `:t foo` might be much slower when just try to add underscores and see results in running `ghcid` daemon.

Comment: Perhaps a quick way to get the type of `foo` could be writing `_ foo` and look at the hole type. Although probably some IDE-like help would be better.

Comment: I agree with @chi that you probably want to use an IDE feature to do this. Type `foo` and hover over it to see it's type. I guess this still requires you to think hard about the type of foo and the type of the result you want if, for example, you would partially apply `foo`. If you type `_` instead of `foo` then under which circumstances does ghci suggest the type of `foo` as relevant?

Answer (score 1):

As @chi suggests, the best thing I've found is "apply the hole to the function". I don't know if this answers the question, but hopefully it is at least somewhat helpful.

I'm guessing that by "functions can always be just partially applied" you mean you can have such a function:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr = undefined
```

for which you can't tell just from the type how many arguments it should take in order to typecheck at any particular type. The best that the typechecker can do here is to tell you the minimum number of arguments it will accept:

```
bar :: String -> String
bar = _1 foldr

* Found hole:
    _1 :: ((a0 -> b0 -> b0) -> b0 -> t0 a0 -> b0) -> String -> String
  Where: `t0' is an ambiguous type variable
         `b0' is an ambiguous type variable
         `a0' is an ambiguous type variable
* In the expression: _
  In the expression: _ foldr
  In an equation for `bar': bar = _ foldr

* Ambiguous type variable `t0' arising from a use of `foldr'
  prevents the constraint `(Foldable t0)' from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `t0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Foldable (Either a) -- Defined in `Data.Foldable'
    instance Foldable Maybe -- Defined in `Data.Foldable'
    instance Foldable ((,) a) -- Defined in `Data.Foldable'
    ...plus one other
    ...plus 22 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
```

Aside: the second error isn't particularly helpful here, as `t0` could really be any of those types. But if you find yourself in such a situation often, then `-fprint-potential-instances` may actually be useful.

You can now do a little bit of typechecking in your head:

```
((a0 -> b0 -> b0) ->  b0  -> t0 a0  -> b0     ) -> 
  <_1>               <_2>    String -> String
```

for the types to match, you must supply at least two holes. You may need more, but that will depend on the instantiation of `b0`. Substituting in these holes, you get a pretty easy problem

```
bar :: String -> String
bar = foldr _1 _2

* Found hole: _1 :: Char -> String -> String

* Found hole: _2 :: String
```

---

You may even encounter a (in my opinion, silly) function like

```
class C a where foo :: a
instance C String where
instance C a => C (Int -> a) where
```

in which case you can do the same thing, and the typechecker helpfully notifies you of all the possible instances:

```
bar :: String -> String
bar = _ foo

test0.hs:6:7: warning: [-Wtyped-holes]
    * Found hole: _ :: t0 -> String -> String
      Where: `t0' is an ambiguous type variable
    * In the expression: _
      In the expression: _ foo
      In an equation for `bar': bar = _ foo
    * Relevant bindings include
        bar :: String -> String (bound at test0.hs:6:1)

test0.hs:6:9: warning: [-Wdeferred-type-errors]
    * Ambiguous type variable `t0' arising from a use of `foo'
      prevents the constraint `(C t0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `t0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance C a => C (Int -> a) -- Defined at test0.hs:3:10
        instance C String -- Defined at test0.hs:2:10
    * In the first argument of `_', namely `foo'
      In the expression: _ foo
      In an equation for `bar': bar = _ foo
```

Here you really have to guess. In this (admittedly contrived) example, I would probably guess you want one argument, because `bar` takes one argument.

```
bar :: String -> String
bar = foo . _

test0.hs:6:7: warning: [-Wdeferred-type-errors]
    * Ambiguous type variable `b0' arising from a use of `foo'
      prevents the constraint `(C (b0 -> String))' from being solved.
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `b0' should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance C a => C (Int -> a) -- Defined at test0.hs:3:10

test0.hs:6:13: warning: [-Wtyped-holes]
    * Found hole: _ :: String -> b0
      Where: `b0' is an ambiguous type variable
```

Now it tells you there is one potential instance, and so you can guess that the type of that hole really should be `String -> Int`.